# Why is my property showing validations even If I didn't explicitly put any [Required] attribute on it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Why is my model property doing validation for `[Required]` even I did not explicitly put any of it in my model class? In the forms in front-end if I left the MiddleName input blank or untouched it shows an error

> The MiddleName is required

My model property looks like this

```
//this is from my EmployeeModel
[Column("MiddleName")]
[StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Maximum of 50 characters and minimum of 2 characters.", MinimumLength = 2)]
public string MiddleName { get; set; }

// and this is from the view (I used template/scaffolded item , with models and context selected, this is for Insert)
<div class="form-group">
     <label asp-for="MiddleName" class="control-label"></label>
     <input asp-for="MiddleName" class="form-control" />
     <span asp-validation-for="MiddleName" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

I already tried putting  `[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]` in the property but it's contradicting my stringlength validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep in mind that there are client side validation and server side validation.

Applying the `[StringLength]` attribute to the property will cause adding  the `data-val-length-max` and `data-val-length-min` attributes to the `<input>` tag for the `MiddleName` property and this will raise the client side validation.

*To see these attributes see the generated HTML document: right click in the browser and select **View Page Source** line.*

But if the `[Required]` attribute doesn't applied or used the [`[ValidateNever]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.validation.validateneverattribute?view=aspnetcore-8.0) attribute the server side validation will not performed for such properties. Therefore, the `ModelState.IsValid` will stay `true` even if properties contains an incorrect value.

To allow an empty string use `nullable` type:

```cs
public string? MiddleName { get; set; }
```

<sup>†</sup> To enable the `nullable` type the project file should contain the `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` line. For example:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
</PropertyGroup>
```

<sub><sup>†</sup> ASP.NET Core MVC</sub>